# Is it possible to update an AngularJS expression via an API call through a Service?

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-services

I'm looking for a way (and not even sure if this is possible) to update an Angular expression on my HTML page when data is sent to an API.

For example, say I have `$scope.message` on my .html page.  Is there a way I can send a message to an API (e.g. `http://...?message=foo`) and have my page update with the message sent?

Also, I need the `$scope.message` to be updated in an Angular Service so it is available to multiple pages within my website.

I am wanting this to be a live update, but if not, I am happy with some code executing on a timer or something similar.

Any suggestions appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I'm guessing it may not be possible, but just in case I haven't explained it correctly, I'll try and simplify it.

I can only find information about using AngularJS to send GET commands **OUT** to a URL and receive data back.  I need to send a JSON string **TO** my Angular site to update a variable.  So basically as a field updates in my database, I want another server application to send an alert to my Angular site to update the status of this value live.  I don't really want to run a constant check of the database if I don't have to.

I am open to any other suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about old school browsers, you can try using WebSocket, it is similar to a TCP socket, which allows you to push from server to client. I would create a service that manages the websocket connection, and update scope when receiving message. Hope this help. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API